# How to remove Value Object within Value Object [DDD]

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have a question regarding DDD.
How do I remove a VO in a VO ?
So I have aggregate x with a VO y.
In VO y there is a list of VO z. zListVO

Now I want to remove a zVO from the aggregate.

Can i do : (method in application layer)

```
public void main 
{
  y.remove(zVO z)
}
```

AGGREGATE X

```
private void Handle(RemovedZDE z)
{
    this.x.remove(z.z);
}
```

And then make a method in VO Y where I remove z from their list of VO ?

Class yVO

```
protected void Remove(zVO z)
{
  zListVO.remove(z);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, instances of the value object pattern are immutable; you don't typically have commands (in the [CQS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html) sense), just queries.

Therefore, it is more common to see something like

```
new_y = old_y.remove(z)
```

> I have aggregate x with a VO y. In VO y there is a list of VO z. zListVO

The basic idea is going to look like:

```
X::remove(Z z) {
   old_y = this.y
   new_y = old_y.remove(z)

   // X is an entity, so we normally update its state directly
   this.y = new_y
}

Y::remove(Z z) {
    old_list = y.zListVO
    new_list = old_list.remove(z)
    // Y is a value, so we create a new value to describe
    // the change
    return new Y(new_list)
}
```

Comment: So value object should always be removed and added again even when only the Value object within is changed (x -> y -> z ). So with that logic it makes sense indeed